# Cachefilesd (cachefiles) everything seems to be set up, still not working

Tags: nfs, cache

I'm trying to set up cachefilesd to work with my network folder shared using NFS.

I have seemingly everything set up, however cachefilesd starts normally, however caching isn't functioning.

Here is output of commands, which I ran in the same order

1

```
sudo mount
...
cache-1:/mnt/datashared on /mnt/nfsshare type nfs (rw,sync,ac,acregmin=3,acregmax=60,acdirmin=30,acdirmax=300,lookupcache=pos,vers=3,fsc)
...
```

2

```
lsbmod | grep cachefiles
cachefiles             40555  1 
fscache                57430  4 nfs,cifs,cachefiles,nfsv4
```

3

```
[edited - deleted]
```

4

```
uname -r
3.8.0-34-generic
```

5

```
grep CONFIG_NFS_FSCACHE /boot/config-3.8.0-34-generic
CONFIG_NFS_FSCACHE=y
```

6

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
```

7

```
sudo service cachefilesd restart
* Restarting FilesCache daemon cachefilesd     [ OK ]
```

8

```
dmesg 
[6211206.141781] FS-Cache: Withdrawing cache "mycache"
[6211210.135236] FS-Cache: Cache "mycache" added (type cachefiles)
[6211210.135242] CacheFiles: File cache on sdb1 registered
[6214644.348929] CacheFiles: File cache on sdb1 unregistering
[6214644.348935] FS-Cache: Withdrawing cache "mycache"
[6214654.575909] FS-Cache: Cache "mycache" added (type cachefiles)
[6214654.575915] CacheFiles: File cache on sdb1 registered
```

9

```
ps aux | grep cachefilesd
root     65399  0.0  0.0   4460   540 ?        Ss   23:14   0:00 /sbin/cachefilesd
1000     65464  0.0  0.0   8160   916 pts/0    S+   23:16   0:00 grep --color=auto cachefilesd
```

finally, biggest problem is

10

```
cat /proc/fs/nfsfs/volumes 
NV SERVER   PORT DEV     FSID              FSC
v3 64476645  801 0:24    233e020f0da07a93  no
```

tl;dr I think I configured everything properly but FSC mount option + fscachefilesd don't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `cat /etc/default/cachefilesd` say?

Is it set to on?

```
# Defaults for cachefilesd initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/cachefilesd

# You must uncomment the run=yes line below for cachefilesd to start.
# Before doing so, please read /usr/share/doc/cachefilesd/howto.txt.gz as
# extended user attributes need to be enabled on the cache filesystem.
RUN=yes # <------ this line needs to be uncommented

# Additional options that are passed to the Daemon.
DAEMON_OPTS=""
```