# NFS with FS-Cache - set up, but still says it's disabled

Tags: nfs, cache

I have about the same problem as [this one here](https://serverfault.com/questions/602203/cachefilesd-cachefiles-everything-seems-to-be-set-up-still-not-working?newreg=ba56d8e6169d4ef8a49894f8adf41005), but that one seems to have been solved because cachefilesd hasn't been enabled. I have it enabled (removed the comment before RUN=yes in /etc/default/cachefilesd) and restarted the service, yet I still get

```
root@pc01:~# cat /proc/fs/nfsfs/volumes
NV SERVER   PORT DEV          FSID                              FSC
v4 86826879  801 0:46         0:0                               no
```

Other outputs from things mentioned in the other post are:

```
root@pc01:~# mount
[snip]
/fscache.img on /var/cache/fscache type ext4 (rw,relatime)
server:/shares on /shares type nfs4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=50,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=xxx,fsc,local_lock=none,addr=xxx)
server:/home on /home type nfs4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=50,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=xxx,fsc,local_lock=none,addr=xxx)
[snip]
```

Yes, I have put the fscache into an ext4 formatted image file, roughly 10 GB big since I didn't want to create a separate partition and Btrfs doesn't support user_xattr for all I know.

```
root@pc01:~# lsmod | grep cachefiles
cachefiles             86016  1
fscache                389120  2 cachefiles,nfs
```

```
root@pc01:~# uname -r
5.16.11-76051611-generic
```

```
root@pc01:~# grep CONFIG_NFS_FSCACHE /boot/config-5.16.11-76051611-generic 
CONFIG_NFS_FSCACHE=y
```

```
root@pc01:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

```
root@pc01:~# dmesg | grep cache
[    0.019397] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear)
[    0.019576] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.043975] random: get_random_u64 called from kmem_cache_open+0x2b/0x360 with crng_init=1
[    0.082514] Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.082543] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.256293] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
[    0.262202] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[   45.997860] FS-Cache: Cache "mycache" added (type cachefiles)
[   45.997863] CacheFiles: File cache on loop0 registered
```

```
root@pc01:~# ps aux | grep cachefilesd
root        1147  0.0  0.0   2876  1172 ?        SNs  14:29   0:00 /sbin/cachefilesd
root        9650  0.0  0.0  21912  2416 pts/0    S<+  14:45   0:00 grep --color=auto cachefilesd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems by default btrfs can't be used for it so I made a ext4 partition and mounted it to /var/cache/fscache with "auto,defaults,user_xattr" attributes. This works now. If anybody knows how to use a btrfs partition for that, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems after a few reboots it activated itself. I now get

```
root@pc01:~# cat /proc/fs/nfsfs/volumes
NV SERVER   PORT DEV          FSID                              FSC
v4 86826879  801 0:46         0:0                               yes
```

Strange but at least it's working

Comment: nevermind. I deleted the ext4 image today because the computer was dead slow with it. I'd like to use the main filesystem which is btrfs. But I don't know if it's capable of user_xattr and if it's already active. Because I just removed the mount so cachefilesd would just write into the directory without the mount, but even after a few restarts it still says not active.